# How to hide navigation menu in pages that are hidden in Navigation Menu in Liferay?

Tags: liferay-theme, liferay-7

In other words, I want to hide the navigation menu from the other private pages that have checked the option `Hide from Navigation Menu` in Control Panel.

In my theme, I am showing the navigation menu on private pages only:

```
<#if layout.isPrivateLayout()>
    <#if has_navigation && is_setup_complete>
        <#include "${full_templates_path}/navigation.ftl" />
    </#if>
</#if>
```

And I want to further hide it in some of the private pages (the ones that the users open as a hyperlink). They are not part of the navigation menu as I have checked the option `Hide from Navigation Menu` - but the navigation menu does show up in them.

If there is no direct way of doing this, how can I get the page name and set the Navigation menu to not display in those pages.

I am using Liferay 7 CE GA2 but I believe this is a generic question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You followed the right track. The only thing missing is the check for `Layout.isHidden()`:

```
<#if layout.isPrivateLayout() && !layout.isHidden()>
   <#if has_navigation && is_setup_complete>
      <#include "${full_templates_path}/navigation.ftl" />
   </#if>
</#if>
```

Comment: I am not sure who downvoted this answer but this works perfectly fine. Just what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch Tobias!

Comment: Before I checked your answer I was doing this to achieve the desired result - I was getting the page name from layout and hiding the navigation menu from a private page as following:

`<#assign the_page_title = layout.getName(locale)/>`

            `<#if layout.isPrivateLayout()>
    <#if has_navigation && is_setup_complete>
     <#if the_page_title !="My Custom Page">
      <#include "${full_templates_path}/navigation.ftl" />
     </#if>
    </#if>
   </#if>`